# ¿Por qué no se guarda la información en un archivo al usar write?

Tags: c++, archivo, c++11

Tengo que almacenar un objeto en un archivo de longitud fija, pero al momento de guardar la información algo sucede y no se guarda. En códigos similares funciona a veces. Me explico. Tengo un código que hace lo mismo; funciona pero solo si el archivo *.txt* existe previamente. Mientras lo compilaba funcionaba e iba guardando cosas, pero en un momento dejó de guardar cuando borraba el archivo *.txt*.

También creo que el archivo no se crea como un archivo binario. Es la primera vez que uso archivos, pero al abrir el archivo la información es legible a excepción de los datos de tipo entero. No sé si tenga que ver pero lo agrego. De antemano, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "correo.h"
#include "archivos.h"
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void agregarCorreo(fstream &file, int tamano);
void abrirFile(fstream &file);

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    int opc;
    int const tamano=sizeof(correo);
    //abrirFile(file);
    do
    {
        cout<<"MENU"<<endl<<endl
           <<"1) Escribir nuevo correo"<<endl
          <<"2) Leer correo"<<endl
        <<"3) Modificar correo"<<endl
        <<"4) Salir"<<endl;
        cout<<"Ingresa una opcion: ";
        cin>>opc;
        switch(opc)
        {
            case 1:
                agregarCorreo(file,tamano);
                break;
        }


    }while(opc!=4);

    return 0;
}

void abrirFile(fstream &file)
{
    do
    {
        file.open("file.txt",ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary );
        if(!file.is_open())
        {
            do
            {
                file.open("file.txt",ios::out);
            }while(!file.good());
            file.close();
        }
        file.open("file.txt",ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary );
    }while(!file.is_open());
}

void agregarCorreo(fstream &file, int tamano)
{
    correo mail;
    int id;
    int posicion;
    char caracter;
    abrirFile(file);
    cout<<"Ingresa los siguientes datos"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingresa la id: ";
    cin>>id;
    posicion=(id-1)*tamano;
    file.seekg(posicion);
    file.seekp(posicion);
    file.get(caracter);
    if(caracter==NULL)
    {
        mail.setIdCorreo(id);
        cin>>mail;
        file.seekp(posicion);
        file.seekg(posicion);
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&mail),tamano);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Posicion no valida..."<<endl;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

correo.h

```
#ifndef CORREO_H
#define CORREO_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;


class correo
{
private:
    //char idCorreo[10];
    int idCorreo;
    char fechaEnvio[10];
    char horaEnvio[7];
    char remitente[25];
    char destintario[25];
    char cc[50];
    char ccg[50];
    char asunto[25];
    char contenido[50*3];
public:
    correo();
    //friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &os, correo &obj);
    friend istream &operator >>(istream &is, correo &obj);

    //char *getIdCorreo();
    int getIdCorreo();
    void setIdCorreo(int &value);
    char *getFechaEnvio();
    void setFechaEnvio(char value[]);
    char *getHoraEnvio();
    void setHoraEnvio(char value[]);
    char *getRemitente();
    void setRemitente(char value[]);
    void setDestinatario(char value[]);
    char *getDestinatario();
    void setCc(char value[]);
    char *getCc();
    void setCcg(char value[]);
    char *getCcg();
    void setAsunto(char value[]);
    char *getAsunto();
    void setContenido(char value[]);
    char *getContenido();
    void generarHora();
    void generarFecha();
};

#endif // CORREO_H
```

Comment: ¿Podrías, por favor, incluir la declaración de `correo`?

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el contenido de `correo.h` y `archivos.h` para reproducir el código? Hay referencias a tamaños que desconocemos, como `int const tamano=sizeof(correo);`. Además, como consejo, deberías evitar el uso de comparaciones como `if(caracter==NULL)`.

Comment: Por cierto, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: tienes ahi un bucle un poco raro, que intenta si o si crear el archivo, pero puede que no se pueda crear por otros temas (por ej, permisos en la carpeta). Has probado a ejecutarlo con sudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que el objeto `correo` es un objeto de tamaño fijo, la instrucción `file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&mail),tamano);` sería correcta cuando `tamano` es `sizeof(correo)`.

Como tu pregunta va sobre objetos de tamaño fijo y archivos, voy a intentar aclarar tus dudas y a darte algunos consejos:

- Si programas en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), usa utilidades de C++. La cabecera `<string.h>` es del lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c), no deberías usarla en C++, en su lugar usa `<string>` (sin la extensión *.h*).
- No mezcles idiomas, *that's not como hablamos the personas, y'know colega?*. Si tienes una función llamada `agregarCorreo` la de `abrirFile` debería ser `abrirArchivo`, o ambas `addMail` y `openFile`, si hace un popurrí de idiomas será más difícil entender tu código pues añades una barrera más a la comprensión.

  - Mejor aún, puedes hacer que las funciones se expliquen por si solas usando los nombres y tipos adecuados `void agregar(const correo &)`, por su nombre y parámetros deja pocas dudas de su cometido ¿no crees?.
- Los flujos de archivo pueden ser de entrada o salida, muy raramente se usa entrada y salida simultáneamente. En lugar de usar un `std::fstream` para escritura y lectura, usa un `std::ifstream` (**I**nput **F**ile **stream**) para leer y un `std::ofstream` (**O**utput **F**ile **stream**) para escribir. **Sospecho que tu principal problema puede estar relacionado con esto**.
- Sigue el [principio de mínima sorpresa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_la_m%C3%ADnima_sorpresa), si tu objetivo es guardar un archivo binario, no uses la extensión de archivo que comúnmente se asocia con texto.

> También creo que el archivo no se crea como un archivo binario. […] al abrir el archivo la información es legible a excepción de los datos de tipo entero.

Que un archivo sea escrito de manera binaria, no significa que su contenido sea ilegible por un humano, significa que la escritura no pasará por ciertas transformaciones que se suelen aplicar a la escritura de texto. Por ejemplo, si escribes de manera binaria el número *mil setecientos cincuenta y dos millones ciento treinta y dos mil setecientos cinco* en un archivo, al abrirlo en modo texto verás la palabra "*hola*", esto sucede porque binariamente ambos datos son el mismo<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>Estoy obviando información de alineamiento y endianess deliberadamente.

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus respuestas, solo para aclarar ya logre hacer que funcionara e implemente los consejos que me dieron, en efecto al usar ifstream y ofstream en vez de fstream la informacion se guarda, pero creo que tambien tiene que ver que no cerraba el archivo al momento de hacer una modificacion, ademas  correo si es una clase de tamaño fijo. De nuevo muchas gracias por resolver mis dudas y aconsejarme sobre mi forma de programar